# Python - any() - Check if elements in list is

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm working on a program where sometimes I have to check if 
a list elements is greater or equal to 0. List elements are always integers.

```
a = [0]
```

In some cases, the list only contains one integer which is == 0:
In this case, I need `True` as the return value of this check.

I thought that I can use [any()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#any) for this purpose.

```
print(any(i for i in a if i >= 0))
```

But `any()` returns `False`. However, if I extend the list `any()` returns `True`.

```
a = [0, 1]
print(any(i for i in a if i >= 0))
True
```

I found a workaround  for this problem but I would like to know why
`any()` returns `False` as long as the list contains one single element.

```
for i in a:
  if i >= 0:
    print('True')
    break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *filtering* the input list, then asking `any()` to test the filtered values. For `[0]`, the filtered sequence is still `[0]` (albeit as a generated sequence, not an actual list), and you are asking if any of those values are true. `0` is a *false value*, so `any()` returns false:

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> genexpr = (i for i in a if i >= 0)
>>> list(genexpr)
[0]
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> any(i for i in a if i >= 0)
False
```

Put the test *at the front of the generator expression*:

```
any(i >= 0 for i in a)
```

That expression doesn't filter, it instead produces a sequence of boolean values, `False` if the test doesn't pass, `True` if it does. For `[0]`, that produces the sequence with a single `True` value, so `any()` returns `True`:

```
>>> genexpr = (i >= 0 for i in a)
>>> list(genexpr)
[True]
>>> any(i >= 0 for i in a)
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Now it is clear to me.